# How to pass term id from the exposed filter block selection to a view pane

Tags: views

I have a requirement to show courses by semester dynamically when semester is changed via an exposed filter.

1. Firstly, I have created a taxtonomy term jumplist view block for semesters. This view block shows as an exposed filter for semesters.
2. Secondly, for displaying courses I followed the following blog and a video (on view panes) to implement the a view pane for courses.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_j3xUpdLEs
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/passing-page-arguments-view-panes

3. Created custom panel page where these views are placed.

The pane page URL works when I manually append an ID to the term URL.

My question is how to pass filter selection from the first jump menu block view (step 1) to the view pane (step 2)?

Comment: sorry your question is a bit complicated , you have 2 different views ? are they related to each other or not ?

Comment: The views are not related.

Comment: I modified my question. I hope its clear now. Thanks.